# Making a print now section for a website

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I have made an invoice system for a website and i want to be able to print just the invoice (Non of the website graphics) so i set up a page that only has what i want to be printed and a button at the bottom of the page that says print now, it does what it says.

The problem is the printed page still has the print button on it obviously. I want to know if there is a way i can have a print button but be able to get rid of the button just for when it prints?

This is the code i am using the print the page:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value=" Print this page" 
        onclick="window.print();return false;" />
</form>
```

So is there a way of doing this, a simple way?

Thanks for the time.

I just realised that i could put the "window.print();return false;" on the "onload" section in the body tag of my HTML, then i can delete the button and all is good.

Comment: Create a print-specific style sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use CSS to target print media:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Add some way to target your print button

```
<input type="button" value=" Print this page" class="button-print" onclick="window.print();return false;" />
```

And in `print.css` hide your button

```
.button-print {
    display:none;
}
```

You can do loads of other stuff to make your page more printable too. [Here's a good article about it](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/05/how-to-create-a-simple-print-css-for-your-site/)

Alternatively you can use a [print CSS media query](http://www.joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/) in your main CSS file, but if you want to support earlier versions of IE (http://caniuse.com/#search=media) you're best going with the first approach.

Comment: Awesome, i have no idea CSS could do this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use css @media print. See css media types http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp.

Answer (score -1):

I just realised that i could put the "window.print();return false;" on the "onload" section in the body tag of my HTML, then i can delete the button and all is good.

This now loads the print preview page in chrome when i click the print link on the previous page.